# How to run 'jekyll serve' pointing to another directory?

Tags: jekyll

Right now I have to be in the directory I want to serve to run "jekyll serve". Is there any way to be in another directory and point to the directory I want to serve from? Something like:

jekyll serve --dir=anotherFolder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it :)

> jekyll serve --source src --destination dist

This will build from the src folder into the dist folder and serve from there.

Comment: this works for me, but if i use bundler (`bundle exec jekyll serve --source ./site`) it is not able to load the Gemfile.

Comment: @ForrestLyman Try `BUNDLE_GEMFILE='./site/Gemfile' bundle exec jekyll serve` without --source.